# The SQL Server Instance That Will not Start

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I needed to attach SQL Server 2008 database to server. There was no log file, just mdf file

After some digging I found this [How to recover database from MDF in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773059/how-to-recover-database-from-mdf-in-sql-server-2005) SO post.
So I tried following steps:

- Create a new database with the same name and same MDF and LDF files
- Stop sql server
- Replace the MDF file with the original

When I next tried to Start SQL Server it failed.

Now it became worse, cannot even start the service. How do I get service back Any idea ?

[image: Error Message when I tried to start the service]

Comment: I think you need to concern your Network Admin for this, see this pinal dave's answer for the fix, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/29/sql-server-fix-error-the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-timely-fashion-consult-the-event-log-or-other-applicable-error-logs-for-details/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just removing the files? It would complain about that, but most probably work..

BTW: When I want to quickly remove some log files (from a development server) I just detach the DB in question, delete the LDF, then attach again, deleting the LDF from the attaching dialog as I do so.. The LDF is not really needed for the attaching process.

Comment: Problem Is SQL service has been stop can not do any thing with out SQL server start.

Comment: Go to the folder where that file is and delete it. Why will that require SQL Server service to be running?

Comment: No need to  run the service to delete that files. but still can not start the SQL server.

Comment: @sansa - do the event viewer report something coming from the SQL server service? This could help into fishing out the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to fix the issue the issue might be help full to some one

```
1). Look at ERRORLOG on SQL folder 
2). Check any Windows Application Error Log
3). Identified problem, and restart the SQL server Single user mode from command   prompt (sqlservr.exe -m) [Help][1] 
4). Repeat 1). and 2). if you get any errors
5). Remove the DB causing issues 
6). Restart the server with multi user mode
```

Problem has been resolved